# ¿Cómo mostrar la información adicional de un input en un lugar fijo en la mima dirección del input?

Tags: css3

Estoy queriendo mostrar información adicional, al hacer click en los campos `input` las acciones funcionan correctamente, el único problema es que no puedo mostrar la información en un mismo lugar determinado pero en la misma dirección del campo `input`.

En el primer campo la información se muestra en lugar ideal, ya en el segundo se sale de su entorno.

```js
$(function () {
$('.note').hide();

$('input').click(function() {
   $('.note').hide();
   $("."+$(this).attr('class')).show();
});

$('input').blur(function() {
   $('.note').hide();
});
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.container:before,
.container:after,
.row:before,
.row:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}

.container:after,
.row:after{
  clear:both
}

.clearfix::after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}

.note {
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
    transform: translateX(-20px);
    top: -5px;
    background: #ecf3f7;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #555;
    padding: 1.2em;
    min-width: 260px;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: .86em;
    line-height: 1.4;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 200%;
}

.note::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 16px;
    border: 8px solid transparent;
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-right-color: #ecf3f7;
}


/* Desing form*/
.maximum, .middle {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

#login,#register {
    height: 100% !important;
    min-height: 800px;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
    padding-top: 20%;
  background: url(../img/system/bg-four.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
}
.content-form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 30px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: auto;
    max-height: auto;
}

.content-form .field {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    min-height: 75px;
}

.content-form .field-block {
  width: 100% !important;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.content-form .field-half {
  width: 50% !important;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.content-form .field input[type="email"], .content-form .field input[type="password"], .content-form .field input[type="text"], .content-form .field select {
    padding: 25px 10px 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    outline: 0;
    border: 1px solid #5ea4b7;
    color: #000;
    height: 50px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .middle {
    float: left;
  }
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
  .middle {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .maximum, .middle {
    float: left;
  }
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
  .maximum {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .middle {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <div id="register">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="maximum">
     <div class="content-form">
      <h1>Regístrese</h1>
      <form autocomplete="off">
       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="field field-half">
         <input type="text" class="note-1" name="first_name">
         <label class="required">Nombres</label>
         <div class="note note-1">Example 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="field field-half">
         <input type="text" class="note-2" name="last_name">
         <label class="required">Apellidos</label>
         <div class="note note-2">Example 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="field field-half">
         <input type="text" class="note-3" name="email">
         <label class="required">Nombres</label>
         <div class="note note-3">Example 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="field field-half">
         <input type="text" class="note-4" name="password">
         <label class="required">Apellidos</label>
         <div class="note note-4">Example 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
       </div>
      </form>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Estoy tratando de mostrar las nota o información adicional así como la siguiente [demostración](https://www.admitad.com/es/webmaster/registration/) si hace click en nombre y en apellido la nota se muestra en un solo lugar fijo en la misma dirección del input.

¿Cómo puedo realizarlo de aquella manera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quita esta línea de .note  en el css:

```
left: 200%;
```

Y pon las siguientes:

```
.note-1, .note-3 {
    left: 200%;
}
.note-2, .note-4 {
    left: 100%;
}
```